# How to get the first id from the INSERT query

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Let's imagine that we have a plpgsql (PostgreSQL 10.7) function where there is a query like

```
INSERT INTO "myTable"
SELECT * FROM "anotherTable"
INNER JOIN "otherTable" 
...
```

So, this query will insert several rows into *myTable*. In the next query I want to collect the ids which were inserted with some condition. So, my idea was to do it the following:

```
INSERT INTO "resultTable" rt
SELECT FROM "myTable"
INNER JOIN ...
WHERE rt."id" >= firstInsertedId;
```

Now the question: how to find this ***firstInsertedId***?

My solution:

```
select nextval(''"myTable.myTable_id_seq"'') into firstInsertedId;
if firstInsertedId > 1 then
    perform setval(''"myTable.myTable_id_seq"'', (firstInsertedId - 1));
end if;
```

I don't really like the solution as I don't think that it is good for the performance to generate the id, then go back, then generate it again during the insertion.

Thoughts:

- was thinking about inserting the ids into variable array and then find the minimum, but no luck.
- was considering to use *lastval()* function, but it seems that it doesn'
  t work for me even though in a very similar implementation in MySQL *LAST_INSERT_ID()* worked just fine.

*Any suggestions?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do both things in a single statement using a [data modifying common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING). You don't really need PL/pgSQL for that.

```
with new_rows as (
  INSERT INTO my_table
  SELECT * 
  FROM anotherTable
    JOIN "otherTable" ...
  returning my_table.id
)
insert into resulttable (new_id)
select id 
from new_rows;
```

---

Another option would be to store the generate IDs in an array.

```
declare
  l_ids integer[];
begin

  ....

  with new_rows as (
    INSERT INTO my_table
    SELECT * 
    FROM anotherTable
      JOIN "otherTable" ...
    returning my_table.id
  )
  select array_agg(id)
    into l_ids
  from new_rows;

  ....

end;
```

Comment: Looks good! I will try those, thanks. Which one you would prefer?

Comment: @Rufi: if you don't need the IDs anywhere else, the first solution